# Flutter - How to implement notifications for a messaging app?

Tags: firebase, flutter, push-notification, triggers, google-cloud-functions

I'm creating a messaging app on flutter and it's using cloud Firestore to receive and store messages. Everything is working fine but I want to add the notifications feature **(when X sends a message to Y, Y gets a notification)**.

I've researched this quite a lot and I didn't find any tutorials for it. All I find are tutorials for FCM that broadcasts notifications.

The only concept I understand now(but I also don't know how to implement) is to **implement a Firestore trigger** when the database is updated to execute a cloud function (onUpdate) that sends a notification to the receiving end.

And for that concept, I also didn't find any documentation for it in flutter or dart. I've used the cloud_functions package from pub.dev and the documentation is only for nodeJS.

Any idea on how to implement this concept? and if it's wrong for a messaging app, I'd appreciate any other better solution.

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Comment: This may help you, Detailed explanation with cloud function as well.
https://medium.com/@duytq94/flutter-chat-app-extended-push-notification-messages-a26c669f4675

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a little late but anyone who wants to know, you need to use Firebase trigger, you can follow the below article.

[flutter-chat-app-extended-push-notification-messages](https://medium.com/@duytq94/flutter-chat-app-extended-push-notification-messages-a26c669f4675)

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you need to work on. First, on server side, you will create a Cloud function that pushes notifications when there is a change on your database. Second, on client side, you will implement the `firebase_messaging` package in order to receive notifications.

Check [this](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/main/Node-1st-gen/fcm-notifications) for setting cloud function and [this](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging) for `firebase_messaging`.

Comment: Unfortunately, the link to the example on cloud functions is broken.